# jQuery UI collapsible tab - how to: run function every time tab becomes active (expanded)?

Tags: jquery-ui, function, tabs

I have a search form in a collapsible tab and I'd like to run a function to set the focus to the first form element every time the tab becomes active:

```
<div id=\"search\">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=\"#search-1\">Search Posts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


$( "#search" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false
});
```

I can't think of a way how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: Check out the [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) event that is thrown by the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `activate` event of the widget:
[api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

Define at tab creation:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
     activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Or bind an event listener:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```